# concatenation of request url to web archive's base url when using fetch api

Tags: javascript, http-headers, fetch-api, google-chrome-console, request-uri

I want to run some script from the browser console for external sites that extracts the dom tree with some format, I did it right but when I wanted to write the result in my file system. this was not allowed due to security issues, so I wrote a backend script using Node.JS that writes into the file system using a post request from the console an reading from the file system while sending a get request on another endpoint.

this is a part of the code I run on the console in which I'm using the fetch API to send my data to the backend (dict)

```
let dict = generateDictionary(root);
const url = new URL("http://localhost:5000/write");
fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ data: JSON.stringify(dict) }),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
})
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

for most of different sites it works well like that

[image: request result over some site]
and this is a snippet from the dom tree after serialization

[image: the text file on the backend]

the problem appears when I use https://web.archive.org/ historical pages to send the same request like https://web.archive.org/web/20220201010705/https://www.reference.com/.

[image]
here as it appears on the snapshot it appends the localhost URL to the web archive's URL. I tried to modify different http headers to solve the problem but all of my trials have failed. what can I do to avoid this concatenation?